# Does every span have a homotopy pushout?

Tags: model-categories

Suppose we have an arbitrary span in an arbitrary model category
$$ B \leftarrow A \to C $$
Is it always possible to complete it to a homotopy pushout square?
$$ \require{AMScd} \begin{CD}
A @>>> B
\\ @VVV @VVV
\\ C @>>> D
\end{CD}
$$

I know that any such span has a cofibrant replacement, and and the pushout of the replacement is a homotopy pushout... but my question is whether or not we are guaranteed such a square exists even if we don't perform a replacement.